# How can i send my recoding file on server with okhttp

Tags: java, android

I am setting up a new file path but I don't why the file is not getting upload

```java
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");


JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject.put("user_id", "1");
    jsonObject.put("file", new File(String.valueOf(new File("/storage/emulated/0/Betyphon/Record_incoming_+919990925305_6242392740563898375.mp4"))));
    jsonObject.put("file_name", "Record_incoming_+919990925305_6242392740563898375");
    jsonObject.put("creation_datetime", "2019-05-27T10:04:16.040757Z");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonObject.toString());

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("http://159.65.145.32/api/file/upload/")
    .post(body)
    .build();

//        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        } else {
            String json = response.body().string();
            System.out.println("File Uploading" + json);

        }
    }
});
```

I want to upload my recording file on the server i tried many way to do it but i can't

Comment: why it didn't work? what exactly was the problem?

Comment: the problem is file is not getting upload on server and when i upload with postman it get success upload

Comment: then probably you do it not the way the server is expecting it.

Comment: you are uploading file path not actual file You have to upload into the multipart form data

Comment: You need multipart body

Comment: Then how can I do it will you help in this?

Comment: Just see: https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-okhttp section 7.4 . I think I had to create json body with upload once and I ended will multipart body

Comment: have you provided necessary  permissions?

Comment: @KaranMer yes i provide all require permission

Comment: if you are check from android 7 or above you need to setup file provider.